# Verifying that the webhook request data came from Wix

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, velo, rs256

I am creating an app for the **Wix** **platform** using the Laravel framework.

I have registered webhooks but now I have to verify that webhook request using PHP. The encryption technique I have to use is the **RS256** algorithm but I can't find any **RS256** algorithm-related function in PHP.

I have also searched for GitHub packages but had no luck.

can anyone tell me how can I verify that webhook request using the **RS256 algorithm**?

Comment: @nice_dev I will test this question...

Comment: RS256 is RSA Signature with SHA-256, with SHA-356 supported by the native [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function that seems like a good place to start.